# BufferedReader to remembe line between functions

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, bufferedreader

Sorry about the, umm.. esoteric title, but here's my question?
If I have a `BufferedReader` within a function, I can make it read line by line, each time it reads a line, it's reading the line after the one it read last time, but consider this:

I have one function that initializes the `BufferedReader`, reads a few lines from a file, then passes that `BufferedReader` on to another function, which then reads a few lines from that same file. Let's say the file contains 10 lines, the first function read 6 lines, the second function read 4.

The question is when the BufferedReader is passed as an argument to the second function, will it start reading the file from the beginning of the file, or will it start from where the `BufferedReader` left off in the first function.

```
BufferedReader br; //initialized somewhere
public void reada(){
    for(int I=0; I<6; I++){
        br.readLine();
    }
    //readb(br); Will calling this(and not the following line) read the first 4 or last 4 lines in a 10 line file?
    //readc(); Will calling this(and not the above line) read the first 4 or last 4 lines in the same file?
}

public void readb(BufferedReader reader){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        reader.readLine();
    }
}

public void readc(){
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++){
        br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `"The question is when the BufferedReader is passed as an argument to the second function, will it start reading the file from the beginning of the file, or will it start from where the BufferedReader left off in the first function."` -- this is quite easy to test, and I suggest that you do just that: write a small program and **test** it.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What reason do you have for beleiving it will magically rewind the file and start again just because you passed it to another method?

Answer (score 0):

Both provided examples will continue to read from where `reada` left off. I believe that, in order to restart from the beginning, one would have to call `close()` then initialize it again. Or just use another `BufferedReader`. I'm sure there are other ways, but that's what comes to mind.

Comment: 'Initialize it again' *means* 'another `BufferedReader`'. These are not two different solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if the BufferedReader is not closed, it will read from where it was last left off. Because they are in the same process context and use the same file handler, so they are using the same "current offset" of the file handler.

Comment: There is no 'both' about it. There is only one `BufferedReader` here.